# Override access to Lua table element

Tags: lua

Is it possible in lua to override access to table element?
F.e. I have a Lua table TBL = {A=1, B=2} and I want to call some function when I use TBL.A instead of getting real TBL.A value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [metatables](http://www.lua.org/pil/13.html) to catch accesses to non-existing elements and several other operations. However, there is no way to directly catch accesses to existing elements, you should build a proxy over your table.

You can check [this proxy implementation](http://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.4.html) to see how it works and adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Wow!

That is exactly what I want.
Thank you!